# How to read huge data CSV file batch by batch in HTML

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I created some HTML to display CSV data in a table using the `d3.csv` function and added pagination with a checkbox to select a particular row.

The problem is to loading data and added pagination, checkboxes for whole data, it is getting more time to display the data in browser.

My code:

```
d3.csv('http://172.21.107.158:3000/uploadcsv', function(data) {
    tabulate(data);
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    });
});
```

How can I read the CSV file batch by batch until data is finished in the file, instead of `d3.csv` function to decrease the duration of loading and display data in a browser?

Comment: you need a paginated API in backend as well here

Comment: You can read the file using a library such as [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse) to avoid loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: How can I paginated in backend. Give me some examples.